# pyreport LaTeX formulae not working

Tags: python, ubuntu, latex, pyreport

I'm trying to create a HTML report using `pyreport` and it works up to the single point, that the LaTeX formulae are not generated.

Here is the input file I use for testing:

```
#$ This is \LaTeX : $c = 2\cdot(a+b)$
```

Than I run `pyreport -l -t html --verbose file.py`, but the report that I get is *empty*. When I add other comments to the input file, or some Python code, than it is displayed properly within the report. Here is the output from `pyreport`:

> Running python script
>   /tmp/file.py:
>
> Outputing report to
>   /tmp/file.html Ran script in 0.13s

I'm using Ubuntu and I have the `texlive` package installed. Why isn't the formula added to the report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i have find the problem.
The problem is the RST tools to convert in html.

In pyreport, when you choose the math mode, the program will do the sentence in a bock

```
.. raw:: LaTeX
```

But in the new version of rst2html, this command doesnt work, it's replace by:

```
.. math::
```

If you use the command:

```
pyreport -l -e -t rst --verbose file.py
```

and after

```
rst2html file.rst > test.html
```

You will see the problem.
You can change that in pyreport code, in main.py of pyreport. (use a locate to find it). And replace the

```
.. raw:: Latex
```

, by

```
 .. math::
```

The last problem is for the command \LaTeX, that's not in a math mode of latex. So it's not work.

You can report to RST documentation http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#raw

Comment: Great, thanks! Works like a charm. For the record: I replaced *all* occurrences of `.. raw:: Latex` with `.. math::` in `main.py`.